# Floating Notifications: How I can develop it?

Tags: notifications

I want learn how to develope floating notifications.

I need any API or Library?, Somebody knows?

Thanks.

Comment: What language and in what capacity? You should be a LOT more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at bootstrap's notifications? You an build your own if you;re keen to do it. Otherwise, you can try [NotifyJS](http://notifyjs.com/). It is simple to understand and easy to use.